# binding redirect json.net from 6.0.0 to 4.5.5

Tags: c#, .net, api, json.net, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm working on a API using .net
For this project i also need to use log4net and gelf4net.

WebAPI uses Newtonsoft.json V4.5.0.0
gelf4net uses Newtonsoft 6.0.0

Then i updated Newtonsoft from nugget but i got an exception saying that Newtonsoft.json 4.5.0.0 cannot be loaded which is normal since i updated.

i made some research and saw that binding redirect thing. i tried one but unfortunately i didn't find out how to make it work ...

Here it is :

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"  />
    <codeBase version="4.5.0.0" href="bin\json.net\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
    <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

i put the old version into a subfolder of bin and a href into the config ..
stil getting the exception.

i saw this on MS website

```
<configuration>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                         newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I just don't understand since it's not possible to add two times the same assembly (even different version), so where the second one is supposed to be located ?
Edit:

also tried using a simple:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0"/>
```

would you have any advice / solution to test ?
thank you !
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround:

- I downloaded the Gelf4net source code on Github
- Replaces the json.net dll by the 5.0.0
- Recompiled it
- added the new dll to my project

Worked perfectly and avoid using several version of the same assembly !